# Groovy extension modules + Maven assembly plugin (fat jar)

Tags: maven, groovy

**Short version**

When `maven assembly plugin` builds a `jar-with-dependencies`, it grabs the first `META-INF/groovy/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModulefile` it finds and ignores all others.

How can I build the project as a fat jar so that it recognizes all Groovy extension classes?

**Long version**

I have a groovy project that that starts with this line of code:

`def today = new Date().clearTime().toTimestamp()`

My project builds and runs fine. I now need to package it into an envelope project - technically, build a separate project with a dependency on my project, as a fat jar (`jar-with-dependencies`, using `maven assembly plugin`) - and run it from ALM (test management software).

Now, **Groovy 2.5.8** consists of a number of modules (`groovy-dateutil.jar` and `groovy-sql.jar`, among others - there is no longer a groovy-all.jar available), and each module has its own `META-INF/groovy/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` file defining the extension classes.

Problem is, when maven assembly plugin builds a jar-with-dependencies, it grabs the first ExtensionModule file it finds, and ignores all others. So whatever groovy dependency I have declared at the top of my project's `pom.xml`, that module's extension classes will be available to me when I run the fat jar, and any others will cause the project to fail on runtime. I can have either `Date().clearTime()`, or `Date().toTimestamp()`, but not both :(

Now, I can manually edit the ExtensionModule file inside the fat jar, adding all the extension classes that I need. However, every time I introduce changes to mu project, I need to rebuild it and the enveloping project as a fat jar (115 Mb), so manually editing the file every time would be tiresome.

I've tried using maven assembly plugin with 'file-aggregate' container descriptor, but it adds the whole content of each file, rather that adding the extension classes to the line `ExtensionClasses=`, so the end result doesn't work either. I've also tried using maven shade plugin, but it did the same thing as the maven assembly plugin. I didn't explore any of its advanced settings though. I've also heard there is a Groovy Eclipse maven plugin.

What should I use to assemble a fat jar with all groovy extension classes working as normal?

**Setup**

```
-Java 11.0.3

-Groovy 2.5.8

-Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5

-IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

-Maven 3.5

-Maven compiler plugin

-Maven build helper plugin

-Maven assembly plugin 3.8.1
```

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#GroovyResourceTransformer

Comment: I tried using maven shade plugin with GroovyResourseTransformer, and it doesn't seem to work. Individual Groovy modules have their extension class descriptors in META-INF/groovy/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule (emphasis on meta-inf/GROOVY/), while GroovyResourceTransformer seems to aggregate the contents of files in META-INF/service/<...>, which does not exist in my fat jar at all!

Answer (score 0):

Apparetly `maven shade plugin` can do exactly what I need (thanks @tim_yates for the info!)

However the current version of the plugin is not quite compatible with the latest version of Groovy, as the location of the ExtensionModule files has been changed.

I've submitted a pull request: https://github.com/apache/maven-shade-plugin/pull/28